# imap_open(): could not open stream

Tags: php, imap

So I'm written a short script which pulls important information from a mailbox on the company server. I'm having no issues with a gmail mailbox which I was testing on as I developed it, but when it came around to testing on my companies mail server I keep getting hit by errors and I've been struggling to resolve this for over a week now. The Error:

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {server:993/imap}INBOX in C:\wamp64\www\emailScraper\getMailbox.php on line 10
```

The line of code:

```
return imap_open('{server:993/imap}INBOX', 'mailaddress', 'password');
```

Thanks for any help, additional information: yes imap is enabled. I've tried with and without ssl enabled. The mail server is exchange 2016. I've noticed a lot of other people with similar issues online, but the solutions are normally vague and haven't worked for me so far. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall?  Have you tried running a shell on the server and seeing if you can connect with a connectivity tool like `openssl s_client` or `socat`?

Comment: No, I used nmap to scan the server, port 993 is open. I'm unfamiliar with those two tools.